# Validation errors using datamapper gem

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

I’m using Datamapper (1.2.0) and Sinatra (1.3.2). I have a model and a property of the model is Employee ID. This is a mandatory field so whenever this is not been entered by the user I need to throw validation error.

Datamapper intelligently identifies the name of the property as 'Employee' (cuts down id part) and displays the error as 'Employee can't be blank' and 'Employee should be an integer'.

So I tried to override these error messages. I could able to override the 'Employee can't be blank' but cannot able to override the other.

```
property :employee_id, Integer, :required => true, :unique => true,
    :messages => {
      :presence  => "Employee ID cannot be blank.",
      :is_unique => "Employee ID should be unique."
    }
```

What should be the hash key I need to use to override the 'not_an_integer' error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message key you’re looking for is `:is_number`. Where this is documented is a bit [hidden away](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-validations/1.2.0/DataMapper/Validations/AutoValidations#generate_for_property-class_method). (I actually looked for it in the [source](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-validations/auto_validate.rb#L217)).

Also, it seems to be if you have any `:messages` hash in the property options then the default messages are replaced with `nil` if you don’t specify a custom message for that validation.

Comment: That worked thanks.. Yes messages are replaced by nil if i didn't specify custom message and i didn't expect that to work like that either.